# Objects with inheritance memory storage

Tags: c++

Say that i have some classes like this example.

```
class A {
     int k, m;
public:
     A(int a, int b) {
          k = a;
          m = b;
     }
};

class B {
     int k, m;
public:
     B() {
          k = 2;
          m = 3;
     }
};

class C : private A, private B {
     int k, m;
public:
     C(int a, int b) : A(a, b) {
          k = b;
          m = a;
     }
};
```

Now, in a class C object, are the variables stored in a specific way? I know what happens in a POD object, but this is not a POD object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the introduction of Chapter 10, Derived classes, the C++ Standard mentions:

> The order in which the base class subobjects are allocated in the most derived object (1.8) is unspecified.

So, in your example `C` objects each have a base class subobject of type `A` and a base class subobject of type `B`, but whether the `A` base member comes before or after the `B` base member is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure if it's required by the standard, in any reasonable implementation I'm aware of they are stored in this order: A::k, A::m, B::k, B::m, C::k, C::m (possibly aligned according to the hardware's requirements). The only practical reason in this knowledge I can think of is that you need to understand that if you cast a pointer to C to a pointer to B, then its value (the address) will be different, so you should be very careful about such casts (don't use reinterpret_cast<> for this, for example).

Comment: This is probably true for many implemenations, but I don't think there's any guarantee.

Comment: @jdv, true, it is probably implementation-specific, but I can't think of any other way it could be implemented. Should add a note to the answer, though.